# Top answerers includes someone who only asked a question

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki

In https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/nicoya-peninsula/info , a tag with currently one question and one answer, the OP is listed as one of the "Top Answerers", even though they only asked the question:

[image: Top Answerers with someone *asking*]

Either the text "Top Answerers" needs changing, or there's a bug.

Comment: Do they have a deleted answer? 'cause it could be caching...

Comment: Actually, that user is [top asker](http://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/nicoya-peninsula/topusers). So there should be top askers column in [info page](http://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/nicoya-peninsula/info) too.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not following...where are you seeing this? The answers and askers seem to be in order here: http://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/nicoya-peninsula/topusers

Comment: @NickCraver: Linked page, right-hand column. I've added a screenshot.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - ahh the sidebar, roger that - I'll take a look

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NIWTl.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will be corrected in the next build.  We total these in one table once a day, and the 0 score for answer case (the owner had a row because he had a question score) was not properly excluded...it will be after the next build, likely tomorrow.